# How did Princess Leia pay Han Solo's reward in Star Wars: A New Hope?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In *Star Wars: A New Hope*, Leia  pays Han Solo his reward for rescuing her from the Death Star. We see him hauling his treasure in the rebel base in metal green boxes:

[image: Scene from A New Hope; Luke in pilot's orange uniform says goodbye to Han, who is handling a greenish-grey box containing part of his reward]

However, the Death Star destroyed Alderaan, Leia's home planet.

With her home planet, and presumably her assets, destroyed, where did Leia so readily get the money to pay Han Solo his reward?

Comment: I always thought the rebels paid him.

Comment: If my hometown was bombed to ruins, I could easily go to a bank branch in another city or even state to withdraw funds.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe If your home *country,* the existence of which is the basis for the value of your money, was bombed to ruins, you might have more difficulty.

Comment: And what exactly was in the green boxes?

Comment: @KSmarts That occurred to me after I commented, but I decided to just let it ride.

Comment: Weapons grade uranium-232. Gold. Sliver Platinum. Rare space rock or bits of paper that have face value back by a planet that has not gone boom. Pick one. It is a rebel force fighting an ongoing conflict; they must have a bank roll or a stock pile of wealth to pay troops and buy machines and ammo. Or if they have so much ammo, etc stockpiled, they could always trade it for pay.

Comment: @KSmarts That depends entirely on the country.  The Euro, for example, is the currency for many countries.  Who's to say that Leia's money is Alderaan-based and not Galactic-based?

Comment: @slytherincess - ta da! you wait three years and all of a sudden, a canon quote comes along...

Comment: If I was the leader of a rebellion or a terrorist organization, I would not let the assets that fund my organization in my bank account, waiting for the official power to take any opportunity to block it. One of the first thing that the USA did after 9/11 was to block (or to try to) Al-Qaeda's funds.

Comment: She subconsciously learned the message from her mother: Never tour the outer rim without something more negotiable than Republic credits.

Comment: She had an insurance policy on the entire planet of Alderaan.

Comment: Didn't you see the Family Guy Star Wars episode? The reward was inexpensive things like bad cheese and a mini lightsaber cheese slicer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Leia was a leader in the Rebel Alliance. She had other resources and contacts than her home planet. She did have to wait until they reached a Rebel base before she could pay him.

Comment: I think she was also an heir (perhaps *the* heir) to Alderaan's off-world assets.

Comment: In the radio drama adaptation (which is pretty cool and  has some nice scenes with Leia before we meet her in the movies), it's noted that Han's reward is to be paid by the rebels.  They spend some time trying to talk him out of taking it since it's a significant chunk of their resources.

Answer (score 34):

This is covered in the film's new Disney canon junior novelisation. In short, his reward (in the boxes we see on screen) is made up of **precious metals that are evidently used in the repair of spaceships.**

> *“We don’t keep that sort of money lying around,” Commander Willard
> said. “And this is…we need every cent to keep up our operations.” **“I’m
> willing to accept the amount in precious metals if you don’t have the
> credits on hand,”** Han said, crossing his arms over his chest. “Come
> on, pal, you don’t want word to get around that the Rebellion can’t
> honor their debts, do you? No one would be willing to do business with
> you.”*
>
> ...
>
> ***“Give him whatever he wants,”** Leia said stiffly. The look she shot Han
> could have incinerated half the Death Star. “The sooner he gets it,
> the sooner he’s gone.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy)</sup></sub>

A similar scene occurs in the earlier [A New Hope: Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_%28junior_novelization%29).

> *Stepping down to the hangar floor, Luke found Han and Chewbacca
> loading small boxes onto an armored military speeder. **The boxes
> contained precious metals, the only form of currency that Han would
> accept from the Alliance. Han had insisted on the payment, even though
> the Rebels desperately needed the materials for repairing starships
> and equipment.** Han appeared to be completely ignoring the activity of
> the Rebel flight crews and pilots.*
>
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope: Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_%28junior_novelization%29)</sup></sub>

Moving down the canon scale, this is also backed up in the (alas, now non-canon) [Star Wars Radio Dramatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_%28radio%29):

> **Leia:** *Captain Solo may have no morals whatsoever, Commander, but he's right. Both Luke and I promised him payment for his and
> Chewbacca's help in this matter.*
>
> **Willard:** *Very well, I see I misjudged you, Solo*
>
> **Han:** *I'll cry later. Right now, I'll settle for cash. In small, used notes if you've got 'em.*
>
> **Willard:** *But this is a Rebel camp! We're hunted people, with very little Imperial currency among us!*
>
> **Han:** *Oh. Well, **your tech facilities must have stocks of precious metals.***
>
> **Willard:** *Yes...*
>
> **Han:** *They'll do.*
>
> **Willard:** *But **those are critical matériel! We need those metals for repairs, to keep our weapons and equipment functioning!***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Radio Dramatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_%28radio%29)</sup></sub>

Comment: Nice find! Alas, Han Solo never did manage to pay off Jabba: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9464/why-hadnt-han-solo-paid-jabba

Comment: Also covered in the new canon novelization of ANH (*The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy*)

Answer (score 1):

Princess Leia was a member of the Imperial Senate. So, she would have indeed assets on Coruscant as well as throughout the Galaxy. Even if we exclude "outside Coruscant", it wasn't a big deal for her to get credits in exchange of her Coruscant assets because Coruscant was a galaxy-class corrupted planet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming she didn't have a personal bank account somewhere she could access. She could very well have pulled some assets from the Alliance. As revealed through the books and other written media, Han was paid in credits, precious metals and spices. Getting the metals and spices suggests payment on behalf of the Alliance to be correct. Han's reward ended up getting stolen before he could pay it which is why Jabba was still after him.

Comment: "Han's reward ended up getting stolen" - canon source?

Answer (score -3):

Han Solo ‘likely’ received the monetary compensation that Obi-Wan Kenobi ‘would have received’ (or would have at least been offered) from the Rebel forces if he had rescued Princess Leia himself.  Also, at the time Kenobi offered Solo the 17,000 credits for transporting him, Luke, and the droids to Alderaan he did not know that Alderaan would be destroyed, or that he would end up sacrificing himself to help Luke, Leia, and the others escape. It’s possible that Obi-Wan had Luke sell his speeder (2,000 credits) to ‘sweeten the pot’ given the risk that Solo was taking to “avoid Imperial entanglements.” All things considered, you can’t really put a price tag on someone’s life, and given how valuable Leia was to the Rebellion, 15,000 credits was a meager sum for them to pay Han Solo.  Still, I wonder, if Princess Leia was worth 17,000 credits, then how much would the Rebellion have paid someone to rescue a captured Mon Mothma?

Comment: According to [Princess Leia, Part I](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Princess_Leia,_Part_I) the bounty the Empire placed on Leia was 10,000,000 credits. Presumably the bounty on Mon Mothma would have been similar.