# Was Princess Leia Organa wealthy?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, economics, princess-leia

Or, more specifically, to amend a catchy title, **how rich was Princess Leia Organa**?

- We know that she was Alderaanian royalty before the planet was Death-Starred out.
- We know from EU that tons of wealthy Alderaanians remained wealthy even after its destruction (e.g., *Tatooine Ghost*, or whatever that book was where Han and Leia hunt for the moss painting after the wedding), so she didn't necessarily have to be poor.

I'm mostly interested in the period after battle of Yavin (in other words, **after Alderaan blew up**) but before formal declaration of New Republic following Episode VI. However, I'm open to answers based on New Republic EU timeline as well.

<sub>I'm looking for canon evidence (Disney, or Legends/EU up to C canon).</sub>

Comment: “Han and Leia hunt for the moss painting after the wedding” — now *there’s* an [Anthology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_sequel_trilogy#Anthology_films) story!

Comment: I hope the answer is yes... that would lend itself to some great memes

Comment: related: [How Did Princess Leia Pay Han Solo's Reward in Star Wars: A New Hope?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10633/5184)

Comment: Since she was adopted into the ruling family of Alderaan, it's probable that she has access to her family's off-world assets. I doubt she has to figure her pocket-change into her budget.

Comment: Rich enough for her dad to have his own star-cruiser, at the very least

Comment: @SJuan76 - italicized paragraph at the very end should clarify that for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She was not very rich AFTER alderan blew up. In the now canon comics Princess Leia it is seen that she has.....no money at all except what the rebel alliance gives her.

IF you think about it (and take the information about the empire and alderan into account it becomes quite clear). With how the empire treats alderans after its destruction they are very probable going to close all bank accounts that can be associated with alderans and give the money to the empires war machine instead.
Thus as soon as a bank account is associated with her publicly it is closed.

The reason behind this is:

> The empire wants to eliminate all alderans.....makes no sense to let them still have any money to use to escape.

For her having no real money (spoilers as it is from the comic):

> The only real treasure she still has is the necklace of her family. She gave it to a sullustan for saving her as she didn't have any medal to give. Furthermore when they land on Naboo, she states that they have absolutely no money and thus had to trick the empire into believing that they are working for them in order to not having to pay the fees at the spaceport.

About page 27 in Princess leia (1?) comic  she stated the no money part.
And about page 62 for the necklace part

Comment: Why -1? However it could use a bit more details as far as citing new canon

Comment: @dvk no clue  but I have stopped asking there a long time ago. what details would you need there? (added a bit more from the Leia comics)

Comment: issue and page # (or screenshot) would be perfect :)

Comment: @dvk added the pages there (hope I didn't miscount the book doesn't have page numbers....furthermore as far as I'm aware the book is in reality multiple comics.......and here we only got the one book collection in the stores so can't tell which part is of which of the separate comics.